# Lithium Ion Battery Charger and Power Path Management IC

Tags: analog, battery-charging

I am to analog electronics. I am building a circuit that has a lithium ion battery. I  understand the importance battery charger in battery management.

My question is how does a designer set specifications of the battery charger IC. What tools are needed?
I would like to use BQ2423x by Texas Instruments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main parameter is the charge rate, or 1C, to determine the maximum current delivered while the battery is being charged. It is important to meet this specification to ensure the battery is not damaged, and to prevent overheating or catastrophic failure. It is equally important to not exceed the maximum charge voltage of 4.2V, nor to discharge below 2.8 to 3.0V. Your design should include protection for the battery to prevent this condition.

Here's a good tutorial about Li-ion batteries. https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

Comment: I was working with the MCP738833 and it has a thing called UVLO under voltage lockout. Is this the protection you are refering to?

Comment: No. UVLO means that if the supply voltage goes below a level that the IC can reliably operate, an on-chip UVLO comparator shuts it down.

Comment: Thank you. Could I then extend my question to: "what sort of protection would be required to prevent the battery from discarging below the value you mentioned?" :)